# Array/Vector u32 'dinâmica' em Rust

Tags: string, conversão, rust, snmp

Estou escrevendo um código cujo o objetivo é converter um OID (SNMP) que está em *string*, para uma *array* `u32` em Rust.

Exemplo:

- OID original: `'1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'`
- OID parsed: `&[1,3,6,1,2,1,1,5,0]`

Escrevi um código que já realiza essa conversão de forma funcional, porém, estou tendo de fixar a quantidade de elementos do `OID` no código:

```
pub fn parse_oid(oid: &str) -> [u32; 14]{

    let oid_array = oid.split(".").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut oid_parsed: [u32; 14] = [0; 14];

    let mut index = 0;

    for id in oid_array{
    
        let tmp_id: u32 = id.parse().unwrap();
        oid_parsed[index] = tmp_id;

        index += 1;
    }

    return oid_parsed;


}
```

Existe algum meio de tornar isso dinâmico?

Exemplo:

```
let mut oid_parsed: [u32; length] = [0; length];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um vetor (ie., Vec). Arrays em Rust são, por definição, estáticas e devem ter tamanho conhecido em tempo de compilação.

O vetor, por sua vez, não tem essa restrição e pode crescer por ser alocado dinamicamente.

De fato, você já está usando um vetor no meio do seu código. O `collect` ali está alocando um `Vec`. Ao invés de tentar gerar um array, apenas continue usando o vetor.

Daria até para usar a API de iteradores para fazer algo mais simples:

```rs
fn parse_oid(s: &str) -> Vec<i32> {
    s.split('.').map(|n| n.parse().unwrap()).collect()
}
```

Vale lembrar que, como apontado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/575661/69296) do Flavio Barros, a função acima resultará em um panic caso um dos termos entre os `.` não sejam passíveis de *parse* como `i32`. Por conta disso, pode valer a pena avaliar outras maneiras de lidar com o `Result` retornado pelo `parse`. [O Livro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) da linguagem tem mais informações sobre isso, se estiver interessado.

Answer (score -3):

Essa é uma solução elegante, mas do jeito que está escrita a função `parse_oid` ela pode falhar dando um panic. Por exemplo, se você entrar com uma string do tipo ""1.3.1.a.2.1.1.5.0" ele vai dar um panic. Nesse caso uma solução mais robusta seria a utilizando o match e Result. Por exemplo:

```
use core::num::ParseIntError;

pub fn parse_oid(oid: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, ParseIntError> {
    let oid_array = oid.split(".").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut oid_parsed = vec![];

    for id in oid_array{
        match id.parse::<u32>() {
            Ok(parsed_id) => oid_parsed.push(parsed_id),
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
    }

    Ok(oid_parsed)
}


fn main() {
    let oid = parse_oid("1.3.1.a.2.1.1.5.0");
    println!("{:#?}", oid)
}
```

e só vai retornar um erro:

```
Err(
    ParseIntError {
        kind: InvalidDigit,
    },
)
```

Você pode testar as soluções no [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021)

Comment: Não há problema em dar um downvote mas não custa nada comentar. Só dar um downvote é pointless.

Answer (score -4):

`fn parse_oid(s: &str) -> Vec<u32> { s.split('.').map(|n| n.parse::<u32>().unwrap()).collect() }`

Comment: Copiar as soluções apresentadas em [outras resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/575640/137387) não agrega valor ao site.